# Standard input/output in C# process

Tags: c#, dll, process, stdout, stdin

My application `App` is using other my application `SubApp`.
When `App` needs `SubApp` it is creating process with `SubApp`, putting data to `SubApp` `stdin` and reading from `SubApp` `stdout`.

The problem is that `SubApp` is using some library which sometimes writes to `stdout`.

Fragment of `SubApp` code:

```
OutsideLibrary.DoSomeInitialization();  // <-- this sometimes writes to stdout
Stream input = Console.OpenStandardInput();
Stream output = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
data = (dataFormat)formatter.Deserialize(input);
//do some job
formatter.Serialize(output, result);
```

Is there any way to prevent code I don't have from writing to stdout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to disable third party component output and you have control over the rest of SubApp code you can do following trick: Redirect standard output to null at application bootstrap. When you need to write something to stdout temporary set standard output back to normal, write and set to null again.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace stdio
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.SetOut(System.IO.TextWriter.Null);
            Console.WriteLine("This will go to > null");
            WriteOutput("This is written to standard output");
            Console.WriteLine("This will also go to > null");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void WriteOutput(String someString)
        {
            Console.SetOut(Console.Out);
            Stream output = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(output);
            sw.Write(someString);
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
            output.Close();
            Console.SetOut(System.IO.TextWriter.Null);
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\nul");
Console.SetOut(sw);
Console.WriteLine("hello!");
```

But it throws an exception in new StreamWriter().

The following might work (call it before your external module becomes active):

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Stream.Null);
Console.SetOut(sw);
```

A workaround would be to open a real text file and delete it.